# Spring Security authenticate external tokens (without password)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have current working product

- clients apps (angular web app or android mobile app) can be logged into social applications (FB, Twitter) using frontend sdk (angular/android sdk)
- they can access our Java backend application, which is secured using Spring security (using username/password login to backend Auth Server)

Now, it is redundancy for the client to attempt another log-in to backend separately using login/password when he already have a valid FB or Twitter token. We are trying to fix this by sending the tokens from front end to AuthServer and retrieving a token from AuthServer(spring-security-oauth2).

Validation of these tokens is what we have achieved in backend, and are also able to fetch the username from the DB. Here is where we are stuck:

1. password is bcrypt encoded so using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, ...)` is not viable. pass
2. Even if we use plain text, somehow JWT token generation is not called.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find out the way to do this yet? I'm struggling about this too.

Comment: @trjade - unfortunately no though this is very clean approach. I have dropped this approach altogether. For now, I am using spring social to use FB login but then I am forcing clients to login to authentication server's login page.